# Get two columns out of a google sheet and put them in a new array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that will get the values of two columns out of a google sheet and put them in an array. I've been able to get the values of the columns in my script but I'm not sure how to join them together. I tried `concat()` but that joined the arrays vertically whereas I want them joined as a table.

```
function getColumnValues(sheetName, lookupName, classificationName) {
  // Get the data range  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var columnHeaders = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0]
  
  // Get lookup values
  var lookupIndex = columnHeaders.indexOf(lookupName) + 1
  var lookupValues = sheet.getRange(1, lookupIndex, numRows, 1).getValues()
  
  // Get classification values
  var classificationIndex = columnHeaders.indexOf(classificationName) + 1
  var classificationValues = sheet.getRange(1, classificationIndex, numRows, 1).getValues()
  
  // Join both arrays together
  var table = lookupValues.concat(classificationValues)
  console.log(table)
}
```

How would I do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
const arr1 = [[1],[2],[3]];
const arr2 = [[4],[5],[6]];
const horizontalJoin = (a1,a2) => a1.map((row, i) => row.concat(a2[i]));
console.info(horizontalJoin(arr1,arr2))
```